# Penalized Logistic Regression wrong coefficient signs using caret train function in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret

I am running a PLR model using the train function with Caret in R. For some reason I am getting the coefficient signs backward. For example if you look at the following code. The sign of the coefficients are correct with the GLM logistic regression but are backward with the PLR.

I know, based on theory and familiarity with the data, that the variables "P_D" and "SHP" should be negative (as seen in the glm summary) and the intercept and "SFB" should be positive.

```
library(caret)
library(stepPlr)
df$y <- as.factor(df$y)

set.seed(88)
modelFit    <- train(y ~ P_D + SFB + SHP, 
                    data = df, 
                    trControl = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number 
= 10, repeats = 3),
                    tuneLength = 3, method = "plr")



summary(modelFit)

stepPlr::plr(x = x, y = y, weights = if (!is.null(wts)) wts else rep(1, 
    length(y)), lambda = param$lambda, cp = as.character(param$cp))

Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std.Error z value Pr(>|z|)
Intercept    -5.03481    2.60165  -1.935    0.053
P_D        3635.74505 1808.31782   2.011    0.044
SFB       -1372.89625  790.51458  -1.737    0.082
SHP         109.73106  575.97467   0.191    0.849

    Null deviance: 68.99 on 49 degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.64 on 46 degrees of freedom
            Score: deviance + 3.9 * df = 16.29
```

GLM

```
model_test <- glm(y ~ P_D + SFB + SHP, 
                     data = df,
                     family = "binomial")

summary(model_test)

glm(formula = y ~ P_D + SFB + SHP, family = "binomial", data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-1.567e-04  -2.100e-08  -2.100e-08   5.099e-05   5.099e-05  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)      20.46    3507.67   0.006    0.995
P_D          -18954.07 2647341.00  -0.007    0.994
SFB            7503.18 1261245.16   0.006    0.995
SHP            -506.06  192973.16  -0.003    0.998

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.8994e+01  on 49  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.0331e-07  on 46  degrees of freedom
AIC: 8

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

---

```
df <- structure(list(y = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L), SFB1 = c(8, 
10, 96, 6.33333333333333, 10, 95, 95, 9, 95, 10, 93, 90, 9, 89, 
98, 96, 99, 98, 93, 9.8, 95, 88, 10, 10, 93, 93, 88, 83, 78, 
10, 96, 99, 92, 90, 86, 89, 90, 96, 97, 10, 97, 98, 10, 90, 87, 
87, 76, 94, 88, 98), SFB = c(0, 
0, 0, -0.0869565217391304, 0, 0.00531914893617021, 0, 0, 0, 
0.0263157894736842, 
0, -0.00819672131147541, 0, -0.0136612021857923, 0.0077720207253886, 
0.0161290322580645, 0, 0, 0, -0.00505050505050503, 0, 
-0.0164835164835165, 
0.0263157894736842, 0, -0.00267379679144385, 0.0166666666666667, 
-0.0294117647058824, -0.0284090909090909, 0, 0.0263157894736842, 
-0.00515463917525773, 0.00769230769230769, 0, -0.00549450549450549, 
-0.0326086956521739, 0, 0, 0, -0.00256410256410256, 0, 0, 
-0.00253807106598985, 
0, -0.00549450549450549, -0.0271739130434783, -0.032258064516129, 
0, 0, -0.0138121546961326, 0), P = c(116, 1910, 31.97, 164, 
20, 116.95, 50.6, 9, 110.24, 8, 257.05, 62.85, 21, 989.99, 13.29, 
29.63, 73.65, 9.2, 209.13, 22.6, 8.7, 8.42, 7, 15, 77.77, 510.72, 
49.95, 18.48, 100.66, 88, 9.98, 24.4, 246.6, 46.24, 21.35, 65.44, 
411.14, 18.16, 16.94, 10, 0.61, 15.99, 2020, 26.85, 50.44, 32.64, 
8.45, 12.41, 30.8, 11.69), P_D = c(0, 0, 0, 0.148221343873518, 
0, 0.0285875706214689, 0, 0, 0, 0.0714285714285714, 0, 
0.00360576923076922, 
0, 0.0208746573504575, 0.00513112884834663, 0.0202809482001756, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0707070707070707, 0, 0.0400898011545863, 0, 0, 
0.125764402961056, 
0.0157120930608288, 0.0263435194942044, 0.172978878368536, 0, 
0.0333333333333333, 0, 0.0729044376614228, 0, 0.0615739616225407, 
0.184294871794872, 0, 0, 0, 0.0257603972687772, 0, 0.0126050420168067, 
0.041299932295193, 0, 0.127776478840309, 0.0987654320987654, 
0.000536727495782858, 0, 0, 0.0236314178850731, 0), SH = c(36, 
24, 24, 20, 36, 36, 24, 36, 60, 0, 24, 24, 36, 108, 36, 36, 24, 
24, 36, 175.2, 24, 60, 1560, 36, 36, 36, 36, 24, 36, 0, 24, 84, 
36, 24, 36, 36, 24, 36, 36, 36, 24, 24, 840, 24, 108, 84, 36, 
36, 108, 36), SHP = c(0, 0, 0, -0.34375, 0, -0.125, 
0, 0, 0, -0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.329545454545455, 
0, 0.214285714285714, 0.477443609022556, 0, 0, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 
-0.5, 0, 0.2, 0, -0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -0.1, -0.1, 0.472222222222222, 
0, 0.25, -0.0625, 0, 0, 0.25, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = 
c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: have a look at the size of the errors!

Comment: Haha yeah this is just the top 20 random rows of a dataset, the actual errors I am getting are not that high. The highest I get with the full dataset is like 2.7. However, this does the job of replicating the error I am having with the backwards coefficient signs.

Comment: have a search on 'separation' : just looking at one predictor `table(df$y, df$SFB==0)`

Comment: Ah yeah so this is why I am using a penalized logistic regression is because I am modeling the difference between observations where Y= 1 and where Y=0 and part of modeling this is taking the difference between those observations so all observations where y=1 will have 0 on the independent variables and then observations where y=0 is the difference from the observation where y=0 (based on a grouping variable not included in the above data).

Comment: For example, SFB is a transformation of SFB1 

mutate(SFB = SFB1 - SFB1[y==1]/(SFB1 + SFB1[y==1])/2)

Comment: There is a grouping variable (not in this data example) so that is why the values are not all the same for observations where y=0.